# Does not Cloud Spanner manage sessions properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-spanner

I have looked up for this issue but could not find any sufficient information about it.

Google Cloud Spanner client libraries handles sessions automatically and its limit is 10.000 sessions for each node, no problem till here.

I have a micro serviced application which also has Google Cloud Functions. I am doing some specific database jobs on Cloud Functions and I'm also calling those functions continuously. After a little while, Cloud Spanner is starting to throw an error;

```
Too many active sessions in database, limit is 10000. Increase the node count to allow more sessions.
```

I know about the limits, but there is not any operation that will cause my app to exceed those limits.

After I noticed this, I have two questions which I could not find any answer;

**1- Does Cloud Functions creates new session for every call? (I am using HTTP Trigger)**

Here is what I did so far;

1- Here is example cloud functions declaration of mine;

```
exports.myFunction = function myFunction(req, res) {}
```

I was declaring my database instance out of this scope before I realize this issue;

```
const db = Spanner({projectId: '[my-project]'}).instance('[my-cs-instance]').database('[my-database]');

exports.myFunction = function myFunction(req, res) {}
```

After this issue, I have put it in the scope like this, and closed the database session after I'm done;

```
exports.myFunction = function myFunction(req, res) {
const db = Spanner({projectId: '[my-project]'}).instance('[my-cs-instance]').database('[my-database]');
// codes
db.close();
}
```

That didn't change anything, it still exceeds the session limit after a while.

Do you have any experience what causes this? Is this related to Cloud Functions or Cloud Spanner itself?

**2- If every transaction object use one connection at a time, what happens in this scenario.**

I have a REST endpoint other than these Cloud Functions. It creates a database instance when its starting to listen HTTP endpoints and I am not creating any other instance in its lifecycle anymore. At that endpoint, I am making CRUDs and I am using transactions and they all use the same instance which I created at the start of process. My experience is;

- Sometimes transactions or other CRUD operations works with a bit delay which does not happen all the time.

My question is;

- Is that because when transaction starts to work, does it lock the connection and all other operations should wait until it ends? If so, should I create independent database instances for transactions on that endpoint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have found the problem, NodeJS library of Cloud Spanner does not work as expected. db.close() function does not kill sessions so that causes the problem. I have reported this bug to Google.

Answer (score 1):

This now has been fixed per the issue opened at [#89](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/issues/89) and the fix at [#91](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/pull/91), and logged as [#71987137](https://issuetracker.google.com/71987137) at [Google Issue Trackers](https://issuetracker.google.com/71987137).

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/71987137) they will re-open to examine.